# jsreport hosting on in-house Windows server not working properly

Tags: windows-server-2012, jsreport

I have recently deployed jsreport on my windows server.
My System config is :

- Windows server 2012 R2 64 bit
- IIS 8.5
- iisnode for 7.X 64 bit

I am getting "400 Bad Request" in response when requesting for report generation using jsreport-browser-client-dist. When I redirect the same request to jsreportonline, It works just fine.

Also during deployment of the jsreport on server, the security tool has removed the following file due to some security concern:

> jsreport\node_modules\winser-with-api\bin\nssm.exe

jsreport Request:

```
{
  "template": {
    "content": "<div>Hello</div>",
    "engine": "none",
    "recipe": "phantom-pdf",
    "phantom": {
      "format": "A3",
      "footerHeight": "140px",
      "footer": "<div>Footer</div>",
      "printDelay": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to jsreport. Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but hopefully this helps someone. The jsreport server appears to need to be restarted any time the "bad request" error gets generated. We've been trialing this tool & it is quite good for most things but quirks like this. That means that if you get that error, then fix the bug that caused it, you'll continue to get the error until you restart the server.